# How to select grandchild - child in xml using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a xml file and i need to select grandchild or grandchild's child using xpath.

Here is xml file link - [XML file](https://pastebin.com/W0fTk9qC)
I do that with this code:

```
<?php
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
        $dom->load('file.xml')

        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

        $nodes = $xpath->query('//question[@id = "1"]/answer[@id = "1"]/subquestion[@id = "1-1"]/answer[@id = "1-1"]');
?>
```

Above code work fine but i need shorten query as i don't know the dept of subquestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the // at any point in the query, so

```
//question[@id = "1"]//subquestion[@id = "1-1"]/answer[@id = "1-1"]
```

can find it at any level below the one your after.

You can always play with these things in something like https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html which allows you to test your expressions.